# JQGrid how can i search an element without html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, jqgrid

i need to know how to search an element with JQGrid single search without tags in html
For example
i have

```
colmodel = [{ 
  name: 'event_Message', 
  index: 'event_Message', 
  resizable: false, 
  sorttype: function (cell) { 
    return getMessageFromSpan(cell); 
  }, 
  stype: 'text', 
  search: true 
}]
```

but when i get datas from server i have to put them in a span (for titles) like in this way :

```
event_Message: "\<span title='" + obj.event_Message + "'>" + obj.event_Message + "\</span>",**
```

When I search with the JQGrid filter I have to search the message with the span , how can i get rows with message without spans??

```
function getMessageFromSpan(cell) {
  var start_index = cell.indexOf(">") + 1;
  var end_index = cell.indexOf("</span>");

  var message = cell.substring(start_index, end_index);

  return message;
}
```

Comment: Please inform us the jqGrid version used. There is a missing important information - where is the search performed - at server or locally? It will be good if the whole jqGrid code is available

Comment: JQGrid v. 4.6.0 , search performed locally.

Comment: I didnt understand, do you want jqgrid i used in mainpage js?

Comment: Since the version 4.6 is very old and is not supported I can recommend you the following: From the server or from the data array do not enclose the field in span - just send it as pure text. To enclose the field in span tag use custom formatter - this way you will have pure data for searching and it will be formatted with the formatter as you want